# I am not able to render JXS Component in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I am building a web app that has React Frontend and Python Backend. The Frontend has a form that takes the keyword using the search box and unit (From dropdown) upon that it finds the results from the backend and displays it on another page that has a table layout but this App is not fully functional because of some issues listed below.

1. I don't know how can I render my JSX component using render_templete as it only takes HTML files.
2. If there is any other way to render JSX?
3. As you know, there is a search box in the Frontend, and the values of the search box will go to the Backend for getting the result but I don't know how to trigger the Backend when the search button is clicked.

Below is my backend code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
app1 = Flask(__name__)
import COSTCOCONVERTQUANTITY
from amazonsupport import searchl
import time
import DOLLARTREECONVERTQUANTITY
from flask_cors import CORS

 
# Initializing flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
 
 
def homew():
    searchbox = ''
    desired_unit = ''
    session = requests.Session()
    session.cookies.clear()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.form['name']
        desired_unit = request.form['unit']
        searchbox = search.replace(" ", "+")
        selected_options = request.form.getlist('options')
        if '1' in selected_options:
            #script that take out the value
 
                table_rowsw += f'<tr><td>{Name}</td><td><a href="{URL}"><button>Buy now</button></a></td><td>{Price}</td><td>{PricePU}</td></tr>'
                counting = counting+1
        else:
            table_rowsw = ''
        if '0' in selected_options: #and '1' not in selected_options and '2' not in selected_options:
           #script that take out value
 
 
            table_rows = ''
 
            for item in data:
                table_rows += f'<tr><td>{item["name"]}</td><td><a href="{item["link"]}"><button>Buy now</button></a></td><td>{item["price"]}</td><td>{item["ppu"]}</td></tr>'
        else:
            table_rows = ''
        if '2' in selected_options: #and '1' not in selected_options:
 
            #script that  take out value
 
                table_rowsct += f'<tr><td>{ctitemname}</td><td><a href="{itemurl}"><button>Buy now</button></a></td><td>{price_float}</td><td>{ppuf}</td></tr>'
 
        else:
            table_rowsct = ''
        if '3' in selected_options:
                if #script that Take out Value
                
                else:
                    ppuf ='N/A'
                    #print('Failed to extract weight')
                #print(driver.title)
                #print('')
                count = count +1
                count1 = count1+2
                table_rowsdt += f'<tr><td>{dtname}</td><td><a href="{itemlink}"><button>Buy now</button></a></td><td>{dtprice}</td><td>{ppuf}</td></tr>'      
        else:
            table_rowsdt = ''
    try:
        return render_template('index.html', table_rows=table_rows, table_rowsw=table_rowsw, table_rowsct = table_rowsct, table_rowsdt = table_rowsdt)
    except :
        return render_template('index.html')
     
# Running app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

As you can see, I am returning values within the HTML tags like this. `<td>{Name}</td>`. Is there any other way to just return values and not with HTML tags?

Here is my Frontend code (Search Form Code):

```
import React from "react";
import "./Hero.css"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Hero = () => {
    return(
<div id="page">
    <div className="container">
        <section className="main-section">
            <div className="flex-row">
                <div className="col-2">
                    <div className="banner-ad">
                        <p>Banner Ad</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-8">
                    <div className="main-form">
                        <h1>BEST PRICE<br/>LARGEST QUANTITY!</h1>
                        <p>Find the cheapest items for sale online by the pound, ounce, gallon, quart, and more!. From Over Multiple venders </p>
                        <div className="my-form">
                            <form action="/" method="post">
                                <div className="inputs">
                                    <input for="name" placeholder="Product name" className="prod-input" name="name" id="name" required="" type="text" />
                                    <select className="unit-select" name="desired_units" id="units" required="">
                                        <option selected="" value="">Select Which Units To Analyze...</option>
                                        <option value="Count">Count</option>
                                        <optgroup label="Weights &amp; Volumes">
                                            <option value="Lb">Pounds</option>
                                            <option value="Oz">Ounces</option>
                                            <option value="Kg">Kilograms</option>
                                            <option value="Gram">Grams</option>
                                            <option value="Mg">Milligrams</option>
                                            <option value="Fluid_Ounce">Fluid Ounces</option>
                                            <option value="Gallon">Gallons</option>
                                            <option value="Liter">Liters</option>
                                            <option value="Milliliter">Milliliters</option>
                                            <option value="Cup">Cups</option>
                                            <option value="Quart">Quarts</option>
                                            <option value="Pint">Pints</option>
                                        </optgroup>
                                        <optgroup label="Computer Measurements">
                                            <option value="Terabyte">Terabytes (TB)</option>
                                            <option value="Gigabyte">Gigabytes (GB)</option>
                                            <option value="Megabyte">Megabytes (MB)</option>
                                        </optgroup>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="vendor-ticks">
                                <div className="vendor-head"><h2>VENDORS:</h2></div>
                                    <div className="vendor-tick-box">
                                        <div className="vendor-tick"><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="amazon" value="0"/><label for="amazon">AMAZON</label></div>
                                        <div className="vendor-tick"><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="walmart" value="1"/><label for="walmart">WALMART</label></div>
                                        <div className="vendor-tick"><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="costco" value="2"/><label for="costco">COSTCO</label></div>
                                        <div className="vendor-tick"><input type="checkbox" name="options" id="dollartree" value="3"/><label for="dollartree">DOLLARTREE</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="submit-btn">
                                    <NavLink to="/search" className="submit-button" type="submit">Check</NavLink>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-2">
                    <div className="banner-ad">
                        <p>Banner Ad</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section className="brands-logo-section">
            <div className="brands-logos">
                <ul>
                    <li><NavLink to="https://www.amazon.com" target="_blank"><img src="./amazon.png" /></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="https://www.walmart.com" target="_blank"><img src="./walmart.png" /></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="https://www.costco.com" target="_blank"><img src="./costco.png" /></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="https://www.dollartree.com " target="_blank"><img src="./dollartree.png" /></NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
    )
}

export default Hero;
```

The page that will show the results in table:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../../components/Header/Header'
import Footer from '../../components/Footer/Footer'
import './Search.css'

class Search extends React.Component{
    
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
              <Header />
              <div id="page">
                <div className="container">
                    <section className="search-result-sec">
                        <div className="flex-row">
                            <div className="col-2">
                             <div className="banner-ad">
                                <p>Banner Ad</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-8">
                            <div className="search-results">
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Product Name</th>
                                            <th>Link</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                            <th>PPU</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                        {{ table_rows }}
                                        {{ table_rowsw }}
                                        {{ table_rowsct }}
                                        {{ table_rowsdt }}
                                        <td><button className="buy">Buy Now</button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                         <div className="banner-ad">
                            <p>Banner Ad</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        </div>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          )
    }
}

export default Search
```

Note that, I am assuming it will achieved by placing just the variables inside the `<tr>` tag like this

```
{{ table_rows }}
{{ table_rowsw }}
{{ table_rowsct }}
{{ table_rowsdt }}
```

I might be wrong so please also suggest to me do I have to apply the map function in the table and if yes then please let me know how.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** run a React app by calling "index.html".

To run a React app you need to **run it on a server** (localhost:3000) `npm start`.

And you can connect it to a backend app (python, node, etc...) by **creating an API and using http requests**.

So you have to create 2 apps:
**one for the front end (React)

and one for the backend (Python)**

**And **connect** them by creating an API (Back-end) and using http requests (Front-end).**

I RECOMMEND WATCHING A TUTORIAL ON CREATING AND USING APIs.

Comment: so you mean I have to create an API of the Backend python code and than have to consume it in the frontend, is that right?